# Twilio push notifications with firebase error: unsupported MIME type ('text/html')

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js, twilio

I am trying to integrate firebase with twilio for push notifications.

First of all I followed [this guide](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/javascript/push-notifications-web) on the twillio official site. They using an old version of firebase so I had to change the **step 6** using [this firebase guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client#web-version-9) and it says to add a `firebase-messaging-sw.js` file in the root of my domain before retrieving a token. But where exactly? I tried adding it everywhere, but it doesn't work.

The console prints me this error:
[image]

I am using next.js with typescript.

Do you have any suggestion on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [next.js static files are served from the `public` directory](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving). The Firebase docs direct you to [add the `firebase-messaging-sw.js` file to the root of your domain](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client#web-version-9), so you should add that file in the `public` directory.